# React Native - How to prevent the modal from closing when user hit the ESC key

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog

When a user attaches a keyboard to a react-native app, and presses the ESC key, it will hide the modal component.  The component is not unmounted so it virtually freezes the entire app.

How do you trap or prevent ESC key from closing/hiding the modal?

Something like this

```
import { Modal } from 'react-native';

<Modal
    onKeyPress={(e) => e.nativeEvent.key == 27 && e.nativeEvent.preventDefault() or e.preventDefault()?
```

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get the key selected is with 'onKeyPress'

```
 onKeyPress={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.key)}
```

and this return the name, for example: 'Enter' or 'Backspace'.
please search the name exactly of the Esc key and create the condition with that.

Comment: the doc => https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html#onkeypress

Comment: Thanks.  Theres a note on the doc - on Android only the inputs from soft keyboard are handled, not the hardware keyboard inputs.

Comment: i find this documentation https://github.com/kevinejohn/react-native-keyevent 
which responds to the native event. 
maybe it works

Comment: Thanks!  It worked like a charm!  Just install the library as indicated in that site.  I did not even put any code after that.